# How to store anim files and retrieve them using sqllite in unity?

Tags: sqlite, file, unity-game-engine, animation

I am making an android based unity project in which it is a feature that a user can view his/her collection of certain .anim files that are stored in DB.

So I have two questions:

1. How can I store anim files in DB using SQLite?
2. How can I retrieve them from DB using SQLite?

I have followed this [link](https://medium.com/@rizasif92/sqlite-and-unity-how-to-do-it-right-31991712190) to learn how to make a DB and store integer values in it, but I couldn't find a way to store anim files in DB.

Can anyone guide me in this matter?

Comment: Why do you want to store files in a DB?

Comment: As there can be a greater number of anim files that the user would want to store and those files will be user-specific. Meaning that each user who will use the unity based app will have their own set of anim files.

Comment: It is usually not recommended to store files in database. Just store the file path or name.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, we try and avoid storing binary data like files, images etc in databases. It would be better to save the `paths to files` in your database if needed.

You could simply save the paths in [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

```
        var files = new string[] {
            "anim 1",
            "anim 2",
            "anim 3",
            "anim 4"
        };

        PlayerPrefs.SetString("anims", string.Join(",", files));

        var saved = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("anims").Split(',').ToArray();
```

Or keep them as more complex objects like `List<MyAnim>` etc and then convert to JSON to save in player prefs.

Comment: I personally would steer away from player prefs as they're not human friendly and just a pain to deal with. They're good for simple settings. If you want to avoid using player prefs then just use JSON serialization, and you'll be able to store much more complex and code&human friendly data.

Comment: Unity's `JsonUtility` cannot serialize complex objects. This means writing additional helpers or using 3rd party assets like [JSON .NET For Unity](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/input-management/json-net-for-unity-11347) (which I use). Perhaps you could elaborate more on "they're not human friendly and just a pain to deal with" as saving the file as JSON via the `File` class to   `Application.persistentDataPath` will save the content in the same way to the same place?

Comment: Newtonsoft can. :D Pain bcz you can't really work with other than few limited types of data and you need to keep track of keys, there's no default value system which adds a lot of boiler plate code checking if things exist. It's not inspector friendly in unity. Obv if you just wanna store a bool then gopher it. Otherwise, newtonsoft is fairly easy to install and use imo.

Comment: But with json, as per you comment, you are saving the content as a `string` either way and it is saved to the **same location in the same format**. The benefit is that all the boilerplate code has been written for you. It's a different situation if you want to serialize the content to a binary format which means having to write a PlayerPrefs equivalent and use `BinaryFormatter` to write/load.

Comment: Yes, on disk it’ll be a string but it will be formatted properly so easy to manually explore and change if ever needed. And the most important benefit it is in code where it’s no longer a string; it’s an object so better in many ways. And if you want to save things like a list of string you don’t need to join them on save, split them on load. Make sure your delimiter never part of an item name. It doesn’t need to be in the same location either if you want it to persist across updates or uninstalls. You can ask to save it anywhere which cannot be controlled for player prefs. It’s simply better.